# Removing HTML from the text in filtering SPGridView

Tags: web-part

I have a WebPart, bulding a SPGridView control with filtering.

I use this code for filtering:

```
grid.AllowFiltering = true;
grid.FilterDataFields = ",Name,Region,Total Sales";
grid.FilteredDataSourcePropertyName = "FilterExpression";
grid.FilteredDataSourcePropertyFormat = "{1} = '{0}'";
```

I have a problem :when filtering a MultyLine column , show text with html tag 
[image]

**How do remove html tag ?**

Answer (score 1):

Try setting BoundField.HtmlEncode = false.

Comment: Thanks , I use this code but don't remove html tag in filtering